# I want an image to fade out and the another to fade in when it is clicked and after that the other way around

Tags: java, android, if-statement, animation

The code below is supposed to fade two `ImageViews`, one needs to fade in and the other out depending on the value of `counter`. For some reason when I run the code I get the following log output:

```
I/Info: One
I/Info Counter:: 1
I/Info: One
I/Info Counter:: 1
...
```

It never shows:

```
I/Info: Two
I/Info Counter:: 0
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Here's the code:

```
public void fade(View view) {
    int counter = 0;
    ImageView bale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bale);
    ImageView pogba = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pogba);

    if (counter == 0) {
        bale.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        pogba.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

        Log.i("Info", "One");

        counter = 1;
    } else if (counter == 1){
        pogba.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        bale.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);

        Log.i("Info", "Two");

        counter = 0;
    }

    Log.i("Info Counter: ", String.valueOf(counter));
}
```

Comment: Please do not take screengrabs of code or error messages.  It makes it difficult for others having this problem to find this question.  Please edit your question to include these in the body of the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a logical error, there is nothing syntactically wrong with your code. The scope of `counter` is where you're having trouble. `counter` is a local variable, it only exists in the `fade(...)` method. Every time you call `fade()` you recreate `counter` and initialize it to `0`. Meaning even though you set it to `1` in the if statement, it will be `0` the next time you call `fade()`. You either need to make it a class variable or use the alternating approach I describe below.

**Non If Statement Alternating Approach:**
You don't need an if statement, simply get the alpha of `pogba` and `bale` and then when you set their alphas use `1f - pogba.getAlpha()` and `1f - bale.getAlpha()` (using whichever method returns their alphas). Using this approach will alternate between `1` and `0`.

So your `fade(View view)` method would look similar to the following:

```
public void fade(View view) {
    ImageView bale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bale);
    ImageView pogba = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pogba);

    // I'm not familiar with the method to get the alpha
    // so it might not be getAlpha()
    bale.animate().alpha(1f - bale.getAlpha()).setDuration(2000);
    pogba.animate().alpha(1f - pogba.getAlpha()).setDuration(2000);
}
```

You would of course need to do the following somewhere else in your code, possibly the constructor.

```
bale.setAlpha(1f); // I'm not familiar with the method to set the alpha
pogba.setAlpha(0f); // it might be setAlpha(), but I'm not sure
```

Comment: I tried your suggested code and now everything works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!